# Html and css remove hyperlink

Tags: html, css

How can i get rid of the underline and the different color because i do not want it to show the hyper link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfcDC.png

Answer (score 2):

You can  use the following code.
Put this code in CSS file

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
a:hover{
  color: black; /* You can use etc. color when user hover on link its change color of text */
}
```

```html
<a href="#!">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove the underline from the hyper link.
Use this code in .css file

```
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

or you can use inline css:

```
<a href="example.com" style="text-decoration: none;">Click here</a>
```

Comment: So it seams to work when doing it on my desktop but not when i upload it to my website

https://breezymods.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Its working fine. trt pressing ctrl + F5 to reset the cache.